# got bad_alloc exception when appending a std string

Tags: c++, stl, std

Consider:

```
int main(){    
    string str("aaaaaaaaaa");        
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
       str += str.data();
    }
}
```

For a large `i`, a "bac_alloc" error occurs.
Is there any way to prevent this from happening?
if there's not, what's the alternative way (to add up a long string)?

Comment: What's wrong with simply writing `str += str;`?

Comment: What exactly do you think is happening? To my calculations you are doing "aaaaaaaaaa" * 2^1000, which equals 1,07150860718626732094842504906e+302 bytes of memory used

Comment: I thought using .data() would fix the problem, but still the same.

Comment: where did you get 2^1000?

Comment: Doubling something again and again, i.e. x*2*2*2*2...., 1000  times, means x*2^1000. I don't know your machine, but I'm quite sure  this will not  work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code `str += str.data()` doubles the string again and again, 1000 times. This would end up in a string of length `10*2^1000`, which is far to much to fit into memory. You probably wanted to concatenate `"aaaaaaaaa"` one thousand times, not doubling the  string 1000 times:

```
string str;
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
   str += "aaaaaaaaaaa";
}
```

Comment: Back of the napkin, it appears that `10 × 2¹⁰⁰⁰` is a very big number.  Larger than all the RAM ever created on Earth, collectively.  More than all the hard drive storage, as well.  A string that large may require an alternative representation.  The entire Earth is comprised of about `1.33 × 10⁵⁰` atoms, so the computer would be approximately the size of a googol of Earths.  Which is a lot.